# References to Random Matrix Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, chaos-theory, randomness, matrix-model

I am looking for some good references - books/lecture notes/articles which contains Random Matrix Theory for Physicists. I am not particularly looking for mathematical rigor in derivations. I am more interested in knowing the general results, and what are the recent developments in that field and relation to quantum chaos.

Comment: Quantum Signatures of Chaos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mehta's book is the classical reference.

I also found these two review articles to be helpful:

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0509286

https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9707301

Answer (score 1):

Is strongly recommend the following book:

Introduction to Random Matrices: Theory and Practice

https://www.springer.com/it/book/9783319708836

Very pedagogical, easy going, and exploiting physics inspired methods such as the replica trick.